Electron process names on production
Electron launches multiple instances/process for each visible window plus main renderer, chrome, GPU and other with the same name,  making it very difficult to find out who's who in the task manager.
Is there any way to to overwrite, or atleast, add a complement to the title to each of the process such as Visual Studio Code or Discord does on Windows?


Try setting process.title

process.title seems to be for internal reference and does not change the process name on the task manager
